# How do you reference a cell under the regular expression parameter in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For instance, how do you fix the parse error in this example?

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?i)A1","***")
```

[image]

I want to maintain the original case of the first parameter assuming it contains multiple sentences, and not convert it to any other case.

Another issue, I was wondering if you could help with filtering plurals using regex. The second image below would be useful for the context of this other issue.

[image]

Comment: You'd yield better help if you provide actual examples of what you are doing. Also note that you can't reference a cell inside a string literal. You can use concatenation using the ampersand for example.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and comment @JvdV Kindly look again, I made some additions

Comment: The concatenation using the ampersand worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, it seems you can use concatenation to reference a cell inside your 2nd parameter. To do so you can use the ampersand:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"(?i)"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","\."),"")
```

[image]

Note that, based on your sample, we need to use `SUBSTITUTE()` too, just to make sure that we escape the use of a dot into dot-literals because otherwise it would match any character other than newline.